# Json table pull in lua

Tags: json, lua

I am looking for help with the json api answer:

```
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "GLG",
        "02. open": "0.4780",
        "03. high": "0.4800",
        "04. low": "0.4650",
        "05. price": "0.4760",
        "06. volume": "14183",
        "07. latest trading day": "2019-10-23",
        "08. previous close": "0.4754",
        "09. change": "0.0006",
        "10. change percent": "0.1262%"
    }
}
```

I would like to pull the variable of `05. price`.

This is my script:

```
return {
    on = {
        timer = {'every 10 minutes'},
        httpResponses = {'MSI'}

    },
    logging = {
        level = domoticz.LOG_DEBUG,
        marker = "msi"
    },
    execute = function(domoticz, item)
        if (item.isTimer) then
            domoticz.openURL({
                url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query? 
                function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSI&apikey=................',
                method = 'GET',
                callback = 'MSI'
            })
        end
        if (item.isHTTPResponse and item.statusCode == 200) then
            domoticz.devices('MSI').updateCustomSensor(item.json["Global Quote"] 
            ["05. price"])
        ))     
    end 
end
}
```

Comment: what is item? json.decode expects a string, maybe you forgot to put the json string into quotes which would make it a table? unfortunately you did not provide your call. also print the table keys, not just the value if you don't know how to index your values

Comment: item is the jresult of:execute = function(domoticz, item)
        if (item.isTimer) then
            domoticz.openURL({
          url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=GLG&apikey=...........',
          method = 'GET',
          callback = 'msi'
          })

Comment: the result of print(type(item)) is table.

Comment: the result of: for x,y in pairs(item) do
                 print(x,y) is Status: dzVents: is  isGroup
 protocol
 HTTP/1.1
 data
 {
"Global Quote": {
"01. symbol": "GLG",
"02. open": "0.4780",
"03. high": "0.4800",
"04. low": "0.4650",
"05. price": "0.4760",
"06. volume": "14288",
"07. latest trading day": "2019-10-23",
"08. previous close": "0.4754",
"09. change": "0.0006",
"10. change percent": "0.1262%"
}
}
 statusText
 OK
 ok
 _contentType
 application/json
 isVariable

Comment: please improve your post. adding content with comments results in an unreadable mess. still missing your json.decode call you say gives an error

Comment: Sorry for the mess, the output of key and values is too big. My code "local k = json.decode(item)"     gives error  
 ":/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/dzVents/json.lua:389: expected argument of type string, got table""

Comment: We can't really help you if you don't even provide any Lua code :|

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: if item is a table and you can print the key value pairs. what is your problem in indexing the value you want? and what do you need json for if you already have a table? sorry I still don't get your problem

Comment: I do not how to pull the value of "05. price" ( wchich is 0.4760 in the example)

Comment: Can someone tell me what command I should use? I tried "item.json["Global Quote"]["05. price"])" but it gives me nil value.

Comment: I added local json = domoticz.utils.fromJSON(item.data) it started to work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

local json = domoticz.utils.fromJSON(item.data) helped